# Plotting normal distributions in a ridgeline plot with ggridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

I'm a little embarrassed to ask this question but I've spent the better part of my work day trying to find a solution, yet and here I am...

What I'm aiming for is a simple ridgeline plot of several normal distributions which are calculated from given means and SDs in my data, like in this example:

```
case_number    caseMean    caseSD
case1          0           1
case2          1           2
case3          3           3
```

All the examples I've found are working with series of measurement, like in the example with the temperatures in Lincoln, NE:
[Example of ridgeline plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMjwN.png)
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html and I cannot get them to work.

As to my experience with R, I am not a complete idiot when it comes to data analysis but proper visualization is something I am eager to learn but unfortunately I need a solution to my problem rather.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit -- added precise theoretical answer.

Here's a way using `dnorm` to construct exact normal curves to those specifications:

```
library(tidyverse); library(ggridges)
n = 100
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(low  = caseMean - 3 * caseSD, high = caseMean + 3 * caseSD) %>%
  uncount(n, .id = "row") %>%
  mutate(x    = (1 - row/n) * low + row/n * high, 
         norm = dnorm(x, caseMean, caseSD))
ggplot(df3, aes(x, case_number, height = norm)) +
  geom_ridgeline(scale = 3)
```

[image]

---

Similar to Sada93's answer, using dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(tidyverse); library(ggridges)
n = 50000
df2 <- df %>% 
  uncount(n) %>%
  mutate(value = rnorm(n(), caseMean, caseSD))
ggplot(df2, aes(x = value, y = case_number)) + geom_density_ridges()
```

[image]

sample data:

```
df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "case_number    caseMean    caseSD
case1          0           1
case2          1           2
case3          3           3")
```

Comment: This is everything I could have hoped for, thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new data frame with the actual distribution values and then use ggridges as follows,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

data = data.frame(case = c("case1","case2","case3"),caseMean = c(0,1,3),caseSD = c(1,2,3))

#Create 100 rows for each mean and SD

data_plot = data.frame(case = character(),value = numeric())
n = 100
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){

  case = data$case[i]
  mean = data$caseMean[i]
  sd = data$caseSD[i]

  val = rnorm(n,mean,sd)

  data_plot = rbind(data_plot,
                    data.frame(case = rep(case,n),
                               value = val))
}

ggplot(data = data_plot,aes(x = value,y = case))+geom_density_ridges()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion! For my needs right now this is sufficient, although I have to increase the number of data points for each case that it mimics a normal distribution, which takes some time on my old machine.

Perhaps somebody has an additional suggestion, that's why I am leaving this open for now.

Again, thank you very much!